# Stage multiple files in gitg

Tags: git, staging, gitg

Is it possible to stage multiple files in gitg? In the commit tab, I can select all the unstaged files but right-clicking (While holding down Shift) to stage does not seem to work. Dragging them also does not seem to work. All I do currently is to right-click->Stage them one by one. Surely, there is an easier way? I'm using gitg in Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: Right-clicking seems to work OK for me to stage multiple files (using Ubuntu 12.04). I wish there was a keyboard shortcut to accomplish this without needing to use the mouse, though.

Comment: What version of gitg are you using? I'm on 0.0.5 and the local repos don't seem to have any update for me.

Comment: I have 0.2.4; I just did the basic `sudo apt-get install gitg`; installed it for the first time a few days ago